# find . -type l says missing argument

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link, find, zsh

I want to find all symbolic links in the current directory and below. Therefore, I used:

```
find . -type l
```

Running that clears the screen showing "Pattern not found (press RETURN)" at the bottom of the screen. After pressing return, I get:

```
find: missing argument to `-type'
```

Here some system details:

- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64Bit
- zsh 4.3.10 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
- happens also in Screen version 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06
- find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2

So how do I search for symbolic links so that I can grep in their names?

Comment: Is this working?
`find . -type l -print`

Comment: Wow, that's odd. Do you get the same issue under bash? Looks like your shell is dropping the last argument.

Comment: No, it also gives the same error message. It is a bit strange, because it first clears the whole screen showing "Pattern not found (press RETURN)" and after pressing return, it shows "find: missing argument to `-type`"

Comment: @JeremyKerr Ah, found it! I have in my .zshrc the following: alias -g l='| less'

Comment: you should answer your own question and then accept your answer. That way everyone knows that this question is solved.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the problem was because of a zsh alias defined as l:

```
alias -g l='| less'
```

As a result, zsh interpreted the l in

```
find . -type l
```

not as the type to look for, but expanded it to:

```
find . -type | less
```

Comment: Please mark this as the answer.

Comment: @saji89 You have to wait 2 days before you can mark an answer as correct.